# Getting LayoutConstraints Warning when setting navigationItem.prompt dynamically

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to set the navigationItem.prompt dynamically after getting a result from a datatask. The data from the datatask itself is listed in a tableview when the datatask completes and the number of items to list in the tableview is supposed to show up in the navigationItem.prompt.

However, I get the LayoutConstraint Warning below when trying to set the prompt from nil to a String.

After some research, I found a similar example [in this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2#toc-anchor-008) (see *Delaying Task Execution*). The same warning shows up after the initial view shows up and waiting for the prompt to be set.

```
2019-07-29 13:48:58.337732+0200 GooglyPuff[34677:3058108] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003c852c0 h=--& v=--& _UINavigationBarModernPromptView:0x7ff015c26540.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c84e10 UILabel:0x7ff015e24660'Add photos with faces to ...'.centerX == _UINavigationBarModernPromptView:0x7ff015c26540.centerX   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c850e0 UILabel:0x7ff015e24660'Add photos with faces to ...'.trailing <= UILayoutGuide:0x6000026bc000'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c84f50 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000026bc000'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(20)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarModernPromptView:0x7ff015c26540 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c850e0 UILabel:0x7ff015e24660'Add photos with faces to ...'.trailing <= UILayoutGuide:0x6000026bc000'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-07-29 13:48:58.339602+0200 GooglyPuff[34677:3058108] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003c852c0 h=--& v=--& _UINavigationBarModernPromptView:0x7ff015c26540.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c84e10 UILabel:0x7ff015e24660'Add photos with faces to ...'.centerX == _UINavigationBarModernPromptView:0x7ff015c26540.centerX   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c84fa0 UILabel:0x7ff015e24660'Add photos with faces to ...'.leading >= UILayoutGuide:0x6000026bc000'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c84eb0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(20)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000026bc000'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarModernPromptView:0x7ff015c26540 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c84fa0 UILabel:0x7ff015e24660'Add photos with faces to ...'.leading >= UILayoutGuide:0x6000026bc000'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, any luck figuring out what is going on?

Comment: @lostintranslation no, I refrained from using this approach altogether...